# How to override component default property values

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the Kendo UI NumericTextBox component for Angular 2 throughout my app. There are a number of properties that I keep setting to the same value. Is there a way to change the default property values at either the app and/or component level?

Here is a simplified example of my current code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-numerictextbox
      [autoCorrect]="ns.autoCorrect"
      [min]="ns.min"
      [max]="ns.max"
      [value]="value1"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>
    <kendo-numerictextbox
      [autoCorrect]="ns.autoCorrect"
      [min]="ns.min"
      [max]="ns.max"
      [value]="value2"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>
  `
})

class AppComponent {
  public ns: {
    autoCorrect: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 99
  };

  public value1 = 5;
  public value2 = 10;
}
```

I'm hoping to have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-numerictextbox
      [value]="value1"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>
    <kendo-numerictextbox
      [value]="value2"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>
  `
})

class AppComponent {
  // Override existing NumericTextBoxComponent default values
  NumericTextBoxComponent.autoCorrect = true;
  NumericTextBoxComponent.min = 0;
  NumericTextBoxComponent.max = 99;

  public value1 = 5;
  public value2 = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the numeric textbox in a component of your own, and manage the default properties there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fwpeRK779thpsv5WJJuj?p=preview

Basically, your new component will look like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'textboxWrapper',
    template: `<kendo-numerictextbox
  [autoCorrect]="true"
  [min]="0"
  [max]="99"
  [value]="value"
></kendo-numerictextbox>`
})
export class NumericTextBoxWrapper  {
    @Input() protected value: string;
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Then, include it in your module's template like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <textboxWrapper [value]="1"></textboxWrapper>
        <textboxWrapper [value]="2"></textboxWrapper>
        <textboxWrapper [value]="3"></textboxWrapper>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

Also, don't forget to add your new component's declaration to your app.module file:

```
import { NumericTextBoxWrapper } from './wrapper.component';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ NumericTextBoxWrapper, ... ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: That solves the issue and it annoying to pass all input\output properties between our components and one from library

Comment: Looks like there is no silver bullet for this issue so far ):